# Voltage difference vs number of electrons

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-current, voltage

When we say a battery has voltage difference, can we deduce the difference in the number of electrons at the two terminals? What does it mean to say there exists a voltage difference?

Comment: It is supposed to be the energy difference of electrons before let's say a resistor and after. But doesn't the voltage source keep accelerating the same electrons after they bounce of atoms? So why does the voltage and with it the energy of electrons decrease after the resistor?

Comment: @YashasSamaga  I searched many times in the internet but I'm looking for simple and easy answers to my questions about fundamentals of electricity like voltage and didn't get any result.

Comment: Have you studied electrostatics?

Comment: Yes but I'm confused about concepts .

Comment: How the hell community knows the question is a duplicate ? :)

Comment: @Theasgardian It is intelligent!